# Swift UITableView Return Cell From Array of Arrays

Tags: ios, uitableview, segmentation-fault, swift

I'm messing around with swift, building a table view controller using pre-generated cells, rather than reusing cells, and I currently have an array that holds arrays of MyCustomCell's, for example:

let sections = [[cell1, cell2, cell3], [cell4, cell5], [cell6]]

Thus, in my numberOfSectionsInTableView I'm doing the following:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        return sections.count
}
```

.. and in my numberOfRowsForSection I'm doing:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
}
```

This is all working fine and dandy. When attempting to grab a cell from its array I'm having a more difficult time, seeing all sorts of different issues and would like to know the best way to implement this. The following, seems to be the simplest method, and I've implemented the same thing in a few different forms, but I get can't even build the project and get the resulting error:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
      var arrayForSection = sections[indexPath!.section]
      var cell: MyCustomCell = arrayForSection[indexPath!.row] as MyCustomCell
      return cell
}
```

> 1. While emitting SIL for 'tableView' at /Users/blah/blah/blah/MyCustomCell/MyCustomCell Example/MyCustomCell
>      Example/ExampleTableViewController.swift:125:14 :0: error:
>      unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 :0: error:
>      swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
>      Command
>      /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>      failed with exit code 254

Not sure what the issue is here, but can anyone come up with a simple implementation to return the appropriate cell and get it to actually compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if what I was seeing with the seg-fault was a bug or not, but changing the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath to the following seems to do the trick:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
        let cellsForSection: MyCustomCell[] = sections[indexPath!.section] as Array
        return cellsForSection[indexPath!.row] as MyCustomCell
 }
```

Alternatively, being more specific about the types when creating the variables makes this more simple.
Changing this:

```
    var sections = []
    var firstSectionCells = []
    var secondSectionCells = []
    var thirdSectionCells = []
    sections = [firstSectionCells, secondSectionCells, thirdSectionCells] // I do this later
```

to this:

```
    var sections: MyCustomCell[][] = []
    var firstSectionCells: MyCustomCell[] = []
    var secondSectionCells: MyCustomCell[] = []
    var thirdSectionCells: MyCustomCell[] = []
    sections = [firstSectionCells, secondSectionCells, thirdSectionCells] // I do this later
```

results in being able to do this instead, which is a bit more concise:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
        let cellsForSection = sections[indexPath!.section]
        return cellsForSection[indexPath!.row]
    }
```